# More than one mismatch [dot (.)] search pattern

Tags: perl

What is the syntax for more than one mismatch ie. dot operator (.) in Perl?
I need to match DNA sequence with target sequence with 3 mismatch allowed.
What will be syntax for that?

For example let DNA sequence ATGC and target sequence is ATGAGCA. After matching, my result should be like below:

```
position no :          pattern
  1                    A...
  1                    .T..
  1                    ..G.
  3                    ..G.
  3                    ...C
  4                    A...
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you show in your patterns, you want `.{3}` for "up to 3" matches you would want `.{,3}`, where `{`*n*`,`*m*`}` is a "quantifier" specifying at least *n* matches, but no more than *m*. If you omit a number, it defaults to either 0 or unlimited.

To match `ATGC` to `ATGAGCA`, I think you might want `/(?:A[^T]{,3}T[^G]{,3}G[^C]{,3}C)+/` and since this is so regular, you could make this expression this way:

```
sub make_match_regex { 
    my ( $fc, @ch ) = split //, shift;
    my $cat = join( '', $fc, map { "[^$_]{,3}$_" } @chars );
    return qr/(?:$cat)+/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $DNA_seq = "ATGC";
my $target_sequence = "ATGAGCA";

my  @tseq = split(//,$target_sequence);
print "position pattern\n";

#4 is the length of the DNA sequence
for(my $i=0; $i<=@tseq-4;$i++) {
  my $str = join('',@tseq[$i..$i+3]);
  foreach my $pattern qw(A... .T.. ..G. ...C) {
    if($str =~ /$pattern/) {
      my $position = $i+1;
      print "$position $pattern\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Output is

```
position pattern
1 A...
1 .T..
1 ..G.
3 ..G.
3 ...C
4 A...
```